# How do I get the Value of strings from a Json?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, get, httpwebrequest

I'm doing a webrequest where I get the result in a Json.
Now in the Json there are strings like:

```
"displayName": "Simon#27756"
```

Now i want to get the "value" which is in this case: Simon#27756
This is how i get the Json:

```
var response = client.GetAsync("webrequest link").Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
dynamic item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

Thanks for your answers!
Have a good day!

Comment: `"displayName": "Simon#27756"` is nto valid JSON by itself. if this part of a JSON object? ie `{ "displayName": "Simon#27756" }`?

Comment: The whole Json starts with the {, "displayName": "Simon#27756" was just one line of the Json.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code you provided all works with your input, all you should have to do is:

```
var displayName = item.displayName;
```

Comment: Thats not working.

Comment: You might have to provide more details, because the code below works in .net 4.7 with all versions of C# that I have installed:

                `dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { displayName = "Simon#27756" }));
            Console.WriteLine(x.displayName);`